# Confusion in using length property to get the event target

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

So, I was going through this [article](https://css-tricks.com/dangers-stopping-event-propagation/) about the danger when using Stopping Event Propagation. There in the section where it is described what else to do instead of using `stopPropagation`, this code is shown:

```
$(document).on('click', function(event) {
  if (!$(event.target).closest('#menucontainer').length) {
    // Hide the menus.
  }
});
```

What I didn't get here is why the `length` property is used in the statement? Isn't the `closest` enough to determine whether the clicked element is the event target?

Comment: See [Is there an “exists” function for jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31044/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest) always returns a jQuery object which is truthy, so of if just check for the value returned by `.closest` it will never satisfies the condition.

Instead the length property of the jQuery object will return the number of dom elements referred by it, so to check whether the closest found the targeted element in the ancestor tree of the `e.target` we can check the length property. If no matching element is found `length` will be 0 else it will have the number of references found

Answer (score 0):

This a very often used 'hack' (I could say *idiom* instead, so widespread). Instead of checking the size of an array is greater than zero, you can shorten the code, by relying on the truthy-falsy properties of JavaScript objects.

```
if (array.length > 0) {
    // do something
}
```

is really the same as

```
if (array.length) {
    // do something
}
```

This predicate is true, when `array` is not falsy, it has the `length` property set, and its value is not falsy (`false`, `0`, `NaN`, `null` and `undefined` is falsy).

In this case we are not using array, but an *NodeList*, but it has a length, so the principle is the same.